# Arrayfun problems in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, function

I'm trying to do a simple speed test in Matlab. I want it to factor 3^a-2 for each a from 1 to 20. Might be I'm choosing too small numbers here to see any significant difference, but I'm stuck anyway.

I tried to write

```
n = [1:20]
m = 3.^n-1
arrayfun(factor,m)
```

this gives a "not enough input parameters" error. I though it made sense but apparently not. After looking at some examples of arrayfun and the manual, i also tried

```
arrayfun(@(m)factor(m), m)
arrayfun(@(m), factor(m), m)
arrayfun(@factor, m)
```

but none worked. What's the correct way to do it? And also if I do speed tests of this sort, will the results be cached so I will have to use different numbers if I do the test again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

`l=arrayfun(@factor,m, 'UniformOutput', false);`

To access use :

`l{1}`, `l{2}`...etc

Comment: Thanks. Will it calulate the factors all at once, or not until I write l{2}?

Comment: @user1661303 yes it will calculate all factors at once, you can check that by omitting the semi-colon at last. This will display cells of each elements

Comment: OK, thanks. Just one more question. What's the difference in this context of writing l(2) and l{2}? I notice the output is different.